# Bootstrap grid isn't centered on tablet device - responsive design

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap grid three squares wide as shown below.

[image]

I have it collapsing into a one-column layout on mobile phones.

[image]

I want it to remain three-squares wide on tablets but instead, it seems to look like this, where it seems to be pushed to the left instead of centered.

[image]

My code is below.  What am I doing wrong?  I tried including code for `col-sm` but it doesn't seem to work.

```css
.worksquare {
  background-color: black;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
}

.work-description {
  color: #303030;
  padding: 10px 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/8c321ca885.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- full container -->

    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 100px;"></div>
    <!-- some header here -->
    <!-- end of header section -->

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-0 col-md-3"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 bottom-buffer30">
        <a href="#" class="work-link">
          <div class="worksquare"></div>
          <div class="lato work-description"><b>Block title</b></a>:
        <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 bottom-buffer30">
        <a href="#" class="work-link">
          <div class="worksquare"></div>
          <div class="lato work-description"><b>Block title</b></a>:
        <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 bottom-buffer30">
        <a href="#" class="work-link">
          <div class="worksquare"></div>
          <div class="lato work-description"><b>Block title</b></a>:
        <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-0 col-md-3"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-0 col-md-3"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 bottom-buffer30">
        <a href="#" class="work-link">
          <div class="worksquare"></div>
          <div class="lato work-description"><b>Block title</b></a>:
        <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 bottom-buffer30">
        <a href="#" class="work-link">
          <div class="worksquare"></div>
          <div class="lato work-description"><b>Block title</b></a>:
        <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 bottom-buffer30">
        <a href="#" class="work-link">
          <div class="worksquare"></div>
          <div class="lato work-description"><b>Block title</b></a>:
        <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-0 col-md-3"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row top-buffer40"></div>

  </div>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason why you have

```
<div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-0 col-md-3"></div>
```

on the start and end of each row?

If you're using that just for spacing purposes, then you're not utilizing Bootstrap correctly. In accordance to their docs, you should be using the col-*-offset classes as described here:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

Eitherway, the main reason your HTML is being shoved to the left is because you're using col-sm-3, which is 25% on tablet size. As you have 3 blocks, it will only fill up 75% of the viewport and it's shoved to the left because of the grid.

If you're using col-sm-4 instead, which is 33%, you will fill up the viewport completely, i.e

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-0 col-md-3"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2 bottom-buffer30">
        <a href="#" class="work-link">
          <div class="worksquare"></div>
          <div class="lato work-description"><b>Block title</b></a>:
        <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2 bottom-buffer30">
        <a href="#" class="work-link">
          <div class="worksquare"></div>
          <div class="lato work-description"><b>Block title</b></a>:
        <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2 bottom-buffer30">
        <a href="#" class="work-link">
          <div class="worksquare"></div>
          <div class="lato work-description"><b>Block title</b></a>:
        <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-0 col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
```

Will appear perfectly fine on tablets.

Answer (score 1):

Remove those empty div's you've got where you've set some classes to "0". They don't work and aren't required.

Then update the div's you want offset, using offset classes. Like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-md-offset-3 bottom-buffer30">
```

Here you are offsetting this div by three grid sizes at the "md" breakpoint and up. You've only got to do that to the first item in the row, to achieve the results you are after.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting